# Set the Camera Position CCScene

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccscene

I've come across an issue with my CCScene. I'm trying to set the position of my scene on the player block. Here is my init for my scene:

```
  - (id)init
{

    // Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return(nil);

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;    

    // Create a colored background (Dark Grey)
    CCNodeColor *background = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0f]];
    [self addChild:background];

    // Add a sprite
    _player = [[PlayerBlock alloc]initWithX:[bp getPlayerX] withY:[bp getPlayerY] maxX:1000 maxY:1000 levelBlocks:blocks endBlock:fb];

    [self addChild:_player];

    self.positionType=CCPositionTypePoints;
    self.position=_player.position;
    // done
    return self;
}
```

Here's my init for player block:

```
    -(id)initWithX:(double)x withY:(double)y maxX:(double)maxX maxY:(double)maxY levelBlocks:(NSMutableArray*)sprites endBlock:(FinishBlock*)finishBlock{
    self=[self initWithImageNamed:@"player.png"];
    self.position  = ccp(x,y);
    _finish=finishBlock;
    _sprites=sprites;
    _startX=x;
    _startY=y;
    _maxX=maxX;
    _moving=0;
    _maxY=maxY;
    self.width=25;
    self.height=25;
    self.positionType=CCPositionTypePoints;
    return self;
}
```

What currently happens is that it doesn't focus on the player block.

Can anyone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add this line to my scene:

```
self.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1000, 1000);
```

As my sprite lay outside of the scene bounds.